# What family of full support probability distributions satisfy that the density of any point in the domain vanishes as the variance goes to infinity?

Tags: distributions, variance, exponential-family

Let $f(x,\sigma^2)$ be a representative element of a family of PDF's with full support over the reals that is indexed by their variance $\sigma^2$. Under what general conditions of the family of distributions can we guarantee that $f(x,\sigma^2)\rightarrow 0$ as $\sigma^2\rightarrow \infty$ for all $x$ in the domain?

I wonder if assuming that all elements in the family have finite variance and are absolutely continuous suffices to have the desired result.

I know that the normal satisfies this condition, but I was wondering if there was a more general family that would guarantee that the density of any point in the domain vanishes as the variance approaches infinity.

Comment: Which type of functional convergence are you interested in? Do you mean zero or infinity?

Comment: Thank you, I did mean infinity (just edited the question). I am interested in point-wise convergence.

Comment: This question is awfully broad because you are asking for a *nonlocal* characterization of the family.  That is, something has to happen for all appropriate sequences of functions $f_\sigma$ *at every real number.* It's easy to construct counterexamples just by taking any family for which your criterion holds and mixing in a fixed continuous distribution with all its members.  If you have an application in mind, then, could you describe it specifically?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried to narrow the question by adding that I am interested in full support distributions over the reals. I also added my current hypothesis of what conditions are sufficient, but would love to see if you think such conditions are not enough and if you have some counterexamples.

Comment: OK, but your reference to "full support on the reals" is a little confusing, because the exponential (aka $\Gamma(1)$) distribution is supported only on the non-negative reals.

Comment: Fair enough, Iet me just forget about the exponential distribution and focus on the normal distribution. In my mind I am equating full support with unbounded support, but of course, these are not the same. I am directly interested in having  the whole real line as support.